# Gmail filter not working when subject field is too long

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I receive lots of emails in my **Gmail** account that are sent to a group `teamname@mydomain.com` and look like this:

```
Author: ...
Date: ...
New Revision: ...
Added (or Modified or Removed): ...
Log: ...
```

So I've created a simple **filter** like this:

```
To: 
teamname@mydomain.com,

Includes the words:
Author, Date, New Revision, Added | Modified | Removed, Log
```

I've checked and it's working fine with emails where the `subject` field is up to about **120 characters**, but sometimes the emails' `subject` have about **900 characters**, and in that case, the filter **is just not working**!

Does anyone have an idea?